# New Dell Inspiron has a 2.5 mm audio port; how to choose an adapter

Tags: laptop, audio

I bought a new Dell Inspiron laptop (Inspiron 15 5566). Unfortunately Dell seems to have changed the port size. My last Dell inspiron had a 3.5 mm audio+mic combo port. This port is smaller. Looks like a 2.5 mm. (Can anyone confirm this? The official specs on the Dell website make no mention of the audio port size so I am a little confused why they would change it)

My HP Headset (HP B4B09PA Headphones with Mic) has a 3.5 mm connector so it does not fit in this laptop. Now 3.5 mm seems to be the standard connector these days. I cannot seem to find any good headsets that are 2.5 mm.

So I was shopping for adapters. But most of them look like they have only three segments on the connector (see photo). That means they won't be able to transfer the mic function from my headset? My HP connector (3.5 mm) has four segments and three insulating rings on it.

Any thoughts? How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: I don't think I've seen 2.5mm anywhere but a few mobile phones... but those did also use TRRS, so you might find an adapter in a phone accessories store.

Comment: I was the idiot! I looked at your post & wondered if it was just a snug fit. I pushed harder & presto it works! I'm embarrassed. If you post as an answer I can accept it!